# Docker: Assign static ip so I can forward from nginx?

Tags: nginx, docker

is it possible to assign a static ip address to the docker container ?

If I have a webserver running in the container on port 8080 then i want to forward all traffic from a certain domain name using nginx, I think i need to supply the ip address of the docker container - right ?

But it is dynamic?

What should I do to be able to do this ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a [custom bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#specify-advanced-options), then uses [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).

```
$ docker network create -d bridge --subnet=192.168.100.0/24 static 

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  myname:
    image: hub_user/image
    ports:
      - 8080
    environment:
      VARIABLE: "value"
    networks:
      mycustnet:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.100.10
networks:
  mycustnet:
    external:
      name: static
```

Comment: You don't even need to create a custom bridge network. You can go with the standard docker network. Typically:

    networks:
      dockernet:
        ipam:
          config:
            - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
    services:
      myname:
      ...
        networks:
          dockernet:
            ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create a docker network, and bind your docker instance to it, or use docker compose. This is clearly explained on https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/14508/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-to-a-docker-container/